# How to add data in Drupal about Brands when adding Testimonials?

Tags: drupal, drupal-7

I am new to Drupal 7. I want to add Brands and under that Testimonials. Is the below approach is correct?

- Add brand has one content type.
- add testimonial has another content type.

While adding a Testimonial I want to be able to select Brands. Is there any way to bring in Brands to the Testimonial content type?

Or is there any other way to implement this?

Answer (score 1):

Create 2 content types, i.e.:

- Brand.
- Testimonial.

Install/enable module [Entity reference](https://www.drupal.org/project/entityreference) (and the modules it depends on). Then add a field to "Testimonial" with a machine name something like "field_brand", which you configure as an "Entity reference", pointing to nodes of type "Brand".

From then on, you should be able to add nodes of type Testimonial, in which you can also select brands.